# Publishing Map With Mosaic Dataset YIelds Grey Image When Zoomed In

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, mosaic

I'm working with ArcGIS 10.0 and ArcGIS Server 10.0 and I'm trying to publish a map that contains a Mosaic Dataset (I believe it's a new data format at 10.0), but after zooming in to a certain extent the ortho greys out.

[image]

I have built/defined overviews and this has helped some ( before building the overviews, I was only getting the Footprint wireframe). The dataset that the Mosaic Dataset is referencing is a single jpeg orthophoto.  If I publish the Mosaic Dataset as an Image Service I get the same results. When creating the Mosaic Dataset, I use all the default parameters and I'm not messing around with visible extents (I'm accepting full extents). Any thoughts as to what's going on here?

Additionally (this may require posting another question),  when I bring the jpeg image into the Mosaic Dataset the quality of the image is greatly reduced, which results in the image looking "over exposed".

Comment: Does the image show up ok within the map document when you zoom in?

Comment: Yes, everything works fine when viewing the image within ArcMap/ArcCatalog.  When zoomed in further than 1:1100, the image turns grey (when published).